# How to verify a key exists in an array

Tags: javascript

I have this variable:

```
var teams = [{manutd: true, barcelona: true, real: false}];
```

Given a string, I want to know if there is an entry in team's entries.
So If I have:

```
var team = "real"
```

I want to query the "teams" and get true as "real" is one of the keys in the array.
I have tried with includes but it fails. Maybe because the keys are not strings?

Comment: `real` is not one of the keys in the array (array keys are simply numeric). `real` is a key in one of the objects in the array of objects. For that reason, your `.includes()` doesn't work because it fails to take into account that you're working with an array of objects, not an array of strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Object.keys`, you can get the keys of the object item in an array.

```js
var teams = [{manutd: true, barcelona: true, real: false}];
var team = 'real';

const isExisted = teams.some((item) => Object.keys(item).includes(team));
console.log(isExisted);
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
var teams = [{manutd: true, barcelona: true, real: false}];
console.log(teams.find(v => v.hasOwnProperty('real')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.keys` to get the keys and check using `includes`

```js
   var teams = [{manutd: true, barcelona: true, real: false}];

    var exist  = Object.keys(teams[0]).includes('real')
 
    console.log(exist)
```